# Can HTML attributes be animated / changed with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a HTML element's attribute with CSS and am not sure how to do it.

I know you can get an attribute with the `attr()` CSS function, but i'm not sure how to change it. For context, I'm trying to animate the `gradientTransform` attribute of my `svg` element. I tried doing it with Javascript, but im not too sure how to animate it infinitely like it would in CSS.

```
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientTransform="rotate(65)">
     <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(220, 60%, 60%)" stop-opacity="1" />
     <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(280, 60%, 60%)" stop-opacity="1" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

I'd like to rotate (change) the `gradientTransform` attribute above infinitely.

Comment: Can you please show the relevant code you wrote in the question. This helps us to understand the context you're working in, and to also create a working example of the problem which makes debugging easier

Comment: Uddated @RoryMcCrossan .

Answer (score 2):

```js
function animateGradient() {
  let angle = 0;
  const gradient = document.getElementById('gradient');

  function updateGradient() {
    angle = (angle + 1) % 360;
    gradient.setAttribute('gradientTransform', `rotate(${angle})`);
    requestAnimationFrame(updateGradient);
  }

  updateGradient();
}

animateGradient();
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(0)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" />
</svg>
```

If you would like to use purely CSS
you cannot on svg but there is a workaround:

```css
  @keyframes gradientBackground {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
  }

  .gradient-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, red);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradientBackground 5s ease infinite;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

  }


  .transparent-path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="gradient-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" class="transparent-path"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The first method seems to work the best. There's only one issue. The gradient isnt centered like in the CSS solution. and the CSS solution has the issue of the background color's square shape overflowing the svg's shape.